# NOT valid mode type SIMetrix from Netlist

Tags: simulation, ltspice, error, pspice

I am trying to run PSpice netlist in SIMetrix .cir and it says

NOT valid mode type SIMetrix from Netlist, do we have to add any command other than this.

[image: Netlist]

[image: Error]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the second parameter of the diode model, the Emission coefficient N (better known as ideality factor or quality factor).

In the Shockley diode equation, this ideality factor is often written with a lower case n.
$$ I=I_S \left( e^{ \frac {V_{\text{D}}}{nV_{\text{T}}}}-1 \right) $$

N typically varies from 1 to 2 (though can in some cases be higher), depending on the fabrication process and semiconductor material.

The default value of N is 1, the case of an "ideal" diode.
It should not be smaller than 1.